# How to add delete effect like iphone application?

Tags: ipad, animation

I have to give a delete thumbnail animation in my ipad application just like iphone/ipad applications delete effect.
Any body help me please sample photo is attached[image]

If you need more details then kindly mention it in comments

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have done this using `CGAffineTransformMakeRotation`. Don't know there is some other better method. But What I have done is my logic you can copy that as it is and you just need to add a delete button on the left top of that view. In the following code I am just animating the thumbnail or any view just like iPad does on its home screen. One thing, You need to declare int direction globally. and every time when you will call this method you will set direction = 1;

```
    -(void)shakeToDelete:(UIView *)shakeMe
{

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.1 animations:^
     {
         shakeMe.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(0.05 * direction);
     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished)
     {

         direction = direction * -1;
         [self shakeToDelete:shakeMe];
     }];
 }
```

/// edit
I tried this way and got it working in my sample screen as attached in photo
[image]

Comment: Thank you @Umair I got it working perfectly and easily. It works great

Comment: If we have to animate all the buttons then we should pass it all the buttons in an array and it will work for all the buttons on that view. this is great

Comment: @Mashhadi hi friend can u help to create this animated i not clear how to give all animated on button thumbnail  my button create according to array image value  and display on scrollview -thank

Comment: @Rocky give me your email id and i will send you a file along with code

Comment: You should not call your animation in cycle, because each time your function is called the device will retain one more animation. A better way is to use just one looped animation. See my post.

Answer (score 0):

You better should use an autoreverse and looped animation, cause creating animations over and over will fulfill the phone memory.

With this code, only one animation is retained.

```
view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-kDeleteAnimationAmplitude);

[UIView animateWithDuration:0.1 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat|UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse animations:^{
    view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(kDeleteAnimationAmplitude);
} completion:nil];
```

Then if you want to stop your animation, just call:

```
[view.layer removeAllAnimations];
```